# Deploying webpart on a single server

Tags: 2007, development

How can I deploy web part on a single server ? I have 5 front end servers in my farm and I have a solution file but i want to deploy web part to only 1 server I know i can add it using STSADM then deploy using -URL but i don't think its most effective.

What else can be done here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stsadm supports solution deployment across all servers in the farm. There is a -local flag which ensures that the solution is ONLY pushed to the box on which you are running stsadm on. Just don't use that an you'll be fine.